# Powershell pull last 5 minutes of data from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a log file that generates new data every five minutes, I am attempting to pull the last five minutes of the log file and pull specific data from the last five minutes.  Currently I have code to convert it from .log to .csv with headers of "Date, Time, Error1, Error2, Error3".  However, every attempt I have tried thus far is not pulling the data correctly.

The Date and Time of the CSV are formatted as: "dd/MM/yyyy","hh:mm:ss.ms"

Powershell does not give any visible errors, but the errorCOLLECTION.csv does not generate

The Current code I have:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\ProgramData\Blah\Blah\Blah Blah\error.log" -Destination "C:\Windows\Blah\Blah\Logs\Temp\Blah Blah\" -PassThru
    
    Import-Csv "C:\Windows\Blah\Blah\Logs\Temp\Blah Blah\error.log" -delimiter "," -Header Date, Time, Error1, Error2, Error3 |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\Windows\Blah\Blah\Logs\Temp\Blah Blah\error.csv"
    
    
    $referenceTime = '{0:dd/MM/yyyy,HH:mm:ss.ms}' -f (Get-Date '2019/02/25,19:09:00.590').AddMinutes(-5)
    $regexSearch   = '\bSdata:\s*\[(\d{2})]'
    
    switch -Regex -File "C:\Windows\Blah\Blah\Logs\Temp\Blah Blah\error.csv" {
        $regexSearch { 
            if (($_ -split ',')[0] -gt $referenceTime) { 
                set-content "C:\Windows\Blah\Blah\Logs\Temp\Blah Blah\errorCOLLECTION.csv"
            }
        }
    }
```

In response to Theo an example of the Log file:

```
29/11/2022,10:48:48.693,PINSP,DC,<PID>6324</PID><TID>2996</TID><F>INFO_GET_KEY_DETAIL</F><X>lpszKeyName [CommsKey]</X><SF>key_lib.cpp</SF><SL>1177</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.693,MDMSP,DC,<PID>6200</PID><TID>5772</TID><G><X>W</X><HS>65535</HS><RI>0</RI></G><F>SXIO::ReceiveIOMessage</F><AR><AN>RetrieveMessage</AN><RV><I4>0</I4></RV><P><N>szMessage</N><S>messageCategory: 0x3 messageType: 0x554cc006 messageID: 0xd6d7928</S></P><P><N>response</N><S>hservice: 43 ucClass: 3 usTLen: 4 TData: [33 01 00 12] ucSLen: 1 SData: [00] ucMLen: 0 ucRSlen: 0 ucRClen: 0</S></P></AR><SF>SXIO.cpp</SF><SL>833</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.693,PINSP,DC,<PID>6324</PID><TID>2996</TID><F>INFO_GET_KEY_DETAIL</F><X>Return Value [0]</X><X>lptKeyDetail [caKeyName [CommsKey] usKeyId [2] usKeyspaceId [4] wTypeOfAccess [0x2] bIsIV [0] bMasterKey [0] bLoadedFlag [1] bIsDouble [0]]</X><SF>key_lib.cpp</SF><SL>1214</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.693,PINSP,DC,<PID>6324</PID><TID>2996</TID><F>INFO_GET_KEY_DETAIL</F><X>lpszKeyName [MACKey]</X><SF>key_lib.cpp</SF><SL>1177</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.693,PINSP,DC,<PID>6324</PID><TID>2996</TID><F>INFO_GET_KEY_DETAIL</F><X>Return Value [0]</X><X>lptKeyDetail [caKeyName [MACKey] usKeyId [3] usKeyspaceId [3] wTypeOfAccess [0x4] bIsIV [0] bMasterKey [0] bLoadedFlag [0] bIsDouble [1]]</X><SF>key_lib.cpp</SF><SL>1214</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.694,PINSP,DC,<PID>6324</PID><TID>2996</TID><F>INFO_GET_KEY_DETAIL</F><X>lpszKeyName [PEKey]</X><SF>key_lib.cpp</SF><SL>1177</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.694,PINSP,DC,<PID>6324</PID><TID>2996</TID><F>INFO_GET_KEY_DETAIL</F><X>Return Value [0]</X><X>lptKeyDetail [caKeyName [PEKey] usKeyId [4] usKeyspaceId [4] wTypeOfAccess [0x2] bIsIV [0] bMasterKey [0] bLoadedFlag [0] bIsDouble [1]]</X><SF>key_lib.cpp</SF><SL>1214</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.694,PINSP,FW,<PID>6324</PID><TID>2996</TID><G><X>W</X><HS>44</HS><RI>2267</RI></G><F>PostWFSResult</F><F>WFSResultData</F><P><N>hWnd</N><PT>263508</PT></P><P><N>lpWFSResult->RequestID</N><U4>2267</U4></P><P><N>lpWFSResult->hService</N><U4>44</U4></P><P><N>lpWFSResult->hResult</N><H>0</H></P><P><N>lpWFSResult->u.dwCommandCode</N><U4>401</U4></P><P><N>lpStatus</N><OB><M><N>fwDevice</N><U2>0</U2></M><M><N>fwEncStat</N><U2>0</U2></M><M><N>lpszExtra</N><PT>00000000</PT></M><M><N>guidlight</N><S>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</S></M><M><N>fwAutoBeepMode</N><U2>2</U2></M><M><N>dwCertificateState</N><U4>4</U4></M><M><N>wDevicePosition</N><U2>3</U2></M><M><N>usPowerSaveRecoveryTime</N><U2>0</U2></M><M><N>wAntiFraudModule</N><U2>0</U2></M></OB></P><SF>FWResultImpl.cpp</SF><SL>4638</SL><E>WFS_GETINFO_COMPLETE</E>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.697,PINSP,FW,<PID>6324</PID><TID>2996</TID><G><X>W</X><HS>44</HS><RI>2268</RI></G><F>PostWFSResult</F><F>WFSResultData</F><P><N>hWnd</N><PT>7014346</PT></P><P><N>lpWFSResult->RequestID</N><U4>2268</U4></P><P><N>lpWFSResult->hService</N><U4>44</U4></P><P><N>lpWFSResult->hResult</N><H>0</H></P><P><N>lpWFSResult->u.dwCommandCode</N><U4>408</U4></P><SF>FWResultImpl.cpp</SF><SL>4638</SL><E>WFS_GETINFO_COMPLETE</E>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.702,Mgr,Mgr,<PID>6324</PID><TID>6588</TID><G><HS>44</HS></G><F>WFSGetInfo</F><P><N>*lppResult</N><OB><M><N>RequestID</N><U4>2268</U4></M><M><N>hService</N><U2>44</U2></M><M><N>hResult</N><U4>0</U4></M><M><N>Code</N><U4>408</U4></M><M><N>lpBuffer</N><PT>280E284D</PT></M></OB></P><RV><H>0</H></RV><SF>MgrApi.cpp</SF><SL>1394</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.702,Mgr,Mgr,<PID>6324</PID><TID>6588</TID><G><HS>0</HS></G><F>WFSFreeResult</F><P><N>lpResult</N><OB><M><N>RequestID</N><U4>2268</U4></M><M><N>hService</N><U2>44</U2></M><M><N>hResult</N><U4>0</U4></M><M><N>Code</N><U4>408</U4></M><M><N>lpBuffer</N><PT>280E284D</PT></M></OB></P><SF>MgrApi.cpp</SF><SL>1230</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.702,Mgr,Mgr,<PID>6324</PID><TID>6588</TID><G><HS>0</HS></G><F>WFSFreeResult</F><RV><H>0</H></RV><SF>MgrApi.cpp</SF><SL>1240</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.703,Mgr,Mgr,<PID>6324</PID><TID>6588</TID><G><HS>0</HS></G><F>WFSFreeResult</F><P><N>lpResult</N><OB><M><N>RequestID</N><U4>2266</U4></M><M><N>hService</N><U2>49</U2></M><M><N>hResult</N><U4>0</U4></M><M><N>Code</N><U4>301</U4></M><M><N>lpBuffer</N><PT>08120D85</PT></M></OB></P><SF>MgrApi.cpp</SF><SL>1230</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.703,Mgr,Mgr,<PID>6324</PID><TID>6588</TID><G><HS>0</HS></G><F>WFSFreeResult</F><RV><H>0</H></RV><SF>MgrApi.cpp</SF><SL>1240</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.703,Mgr,Mgr,<PID>6324</PID><TID>6588</TID><G><HS>0</HS></G><F>WFSFreeResult</F><P><N>lpResult</N><OB><M><N>RequestID</N><U4>2267</U4></M><M><N>hService</N><U2>44</U2></M><M><N>hResult</N><U4>0</U4></M><M><N>Code</N><U4>401</U4></M><M><N>lpBuffer</N><PT>281523A5</PT></M></OB></P><SF>MgrApi.cpp</SF><SL>1230</SL>
29/11/2022,10:48:48.703,Mgr,Mgr,<PID>6324</PID><TID>6588</TID><G><HS>0</HS></G><F>WFSFreeResult</F><RV><H>0</H></RV><SF>MgrApi.cpp</SF><SL>1240</SL>
```

Comment: what content are you trying to set to errorCOLLECTION.csv? You need to pass a `-Value` parameter to `Set-Content` as well.

Comment: Ultimately it will be information related to an error code called "SData", my current plan is after I can successfully pull just the last 5 minutes of the log I can iterate over that to get the desired content.

Comment: Why are you using "split".  Import-Csv will remove the commas.

Comment: well if you aren't giving the file any content to set, why would it generate the file?

Comment: Im brand new to powershell and still learning as I go.  Thank you jdweng for pointing that aspect out. Also thank you frankM_DN for pointing to the logic. Much appreciated!

Comment: The way you do `$referenceTime` just gives you a **string**, not a DateTime object to compare against. Then you try to compare that against another string, but because the date format you use is not sortable, there is no way you can get that right. Next, why create an in-between CSV file and then use `switch -File` on it? That will read the file line-by-line and does no object parsing whatsoever. If you want help, then [edit] your question and show us some of that log file

Comment: Thank you Theo, would it better to give example of the raw log file or of the CSV with headers of the log?

Comment: Probably best to give an example of the log file itself, so we can see if using `Import-Csv` on it would indeed return something valid

Comment: When you say "pull the last five minutes of the log file" - is it the last 5 minutes relative to the last line logged, or the last 5 minutes relative to the current time?

Comment: CrookedJ - Last 5 relative to current time, it may generate 200 lines in 5 minutes or 3000 lines so I can't use -tail as the specific entry I need could be on line 1245 or 15

Comment: Please can you edit again, because now you have formatted your example as blockquote which removes the tags that seem to be in there. Just the raw text would be fine, preceded by a line of triple backticks and also closed with a line of triple backticks.

Comment: Add text in a java box (has <> ) so data doesn't get changed.

Comment: unless im missing something, from the provided example log file, there is no line that could match your regex pattern `\bSdata:\s*\[(\d{2})]`

Comment: a five minute pull can be 2000+ lines and the Sdata field can be generated on any of those.  Instead of posting a huge log, I just took the last few as a lay out.  I could be wrong but think there should be some way since the start of each line is always Date,Time, to only pull the last 5 minutes of data and ignore the other 12 hours prior.  I have the rest of the script functioning to pull the data I need from the remainder.

Comment: added a line that includes the SData portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a slight modification to your code, because `($_ -split ',')[0]` would be only targeting the **Date and not the Time**, the following works properly for me outputting the line starting with:

```
29/11/2022,10:48:48.693,MDMSP,DC,<PID>6200...
```

I'm also using [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-7.0) to convert these strings into a [`DateTime` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0), I'm honestly not sure comparing these strings as strings would work correctly, at least converting them to `DateTime` instances we're 100% sure the comparison will be correct.

Aside from that, as was pointed out in comments by other users, [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) currently has the path to output but no value as argument.

```bash
& {
    $referenceTime = (Get-Date '2019/02/25,19:09:00.590').AddMinutes(-5)
    $regexSearch   = '\bSdata:\s*\[(\d{2})]'
    $parsedDate    = [ref] [datetime]::new(0)
    
    switch -Regex -File 'C:\bla\bla\error.csv' {
        $regexSearch {
            $success = [datetime]::TryParseExact(
                ('{0},{1}' -f $_.Split(',', 3)[0, 1]),
                'dd/MM/yyyy,HH:mm:ss.fff',
                [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,
                [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::AssumeLocal,
                $parsedDate
            )
    
            if($success -and $parsedDate.Value -gt $referenceTime) {
                $_
            }
        }
    }
} | Set-Content 'C:\bla\bla\errorCOLLECTION.csv'
```